# How to use .getRange(x,y,n,m) in google sheets with row and column numer like variables?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I defined two variables called "filas" and "columnas". In that cells, I use a formula to get the number of rows and columns that are not empy. So, I want to use .getRange to obtain data from a table, but it doesn't fuction using the number of rows and colums like variables .getRange(2,2,filas,columnas).
How can i solve this?

`var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
 var filas= values[0][1];
 var columnas= values[1][0];`

`var sigla1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(2,2,filas,columnas).getValues();`

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing an example of what value `filas` and `columnas` have, we can't do much for you. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Comment: Is it perhaps that instead of getActiveSpreadsheet() it should be `var sigla1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2,filas,columnas).getValues();`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first to try filas and columnas with a hardcoded value. If that works, then you need to check the values in the values array.

**Update**

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` does not have `getRange(x, y, n, m)` function. You need to

either get a `Sheet` object from the `Spreadsheet` object and use the `getRange(x, y, n, m)` in the `Sheet` object

or

use `getRange(a1Notation)` function of `Spreadsheet` object

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

Comment: I tried to set the values of "columnas" and "filas" as a fixed value but it doesn't word. The error is "No se puede encontrar el método getRange(number,number,number,number)".. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, supose I use getRange(a1Notation), How can i do for the number of row to change if change the variable "filas"? var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
 var filas= values[0][1];
 var columnas= values[1][0];

var sigla1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B&filas&:I&filas&").getValues(); ?

Comment: a1Notation = <sheetName>!<startColumn><startRow>:<endColumn><endRow> (e.g. Sheet1!A2:B50). String concatenation in Javascript works with + symbol (e.g. 'A' + varName + ':B' + varName)